# JS Popover API: prevent event propagation on backdrop interaction

Tags: javascript, popover

In this example from MDN: https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/popover-api/blur-background/

If I open the popover, and click again on the button in the background, the popover stays because the following events occur:

```
Popover.onbeforetoggle // open -> close
button.onclick
Popover.onbeforetoggle // close -> open, as a result of button.onclick
```

I do not want the user to be able to interact with anything under the top layer of the website, while still allowing to close the popover when clicking on the backdrop.

So, when the backdrop is clicked, I do not want the click event to propagate.

Is there any way to do so?

I do not wish to use 3rd party libraries.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's how a popover works.

Try to use `<dialog>` instead or make the popover as a backdrop for an internal DIV acting as an actual popover.
Then you can catch clicks and do anything you want.

If you want the backdrop transparent for mouse events in certain situations you could trigger them manually on an element under the mouse pointer (`document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)`):

```js
const popover = document.querySelector("[popover]");


popover.showPopover(); popover.classList.toggle('opened');
popover.addEventListener('beforetoggle', e => popover.classList.toggle('opened', e.newState !== 'closed'));
popover.addEventListener("click", e => e.target.closest('.popover') || popover.hidePopover());
```

```css
.popover{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .backdrop{
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: transparent;
    }
    
    .opened{
      display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log('button clicked')">Click me</button>
<button onclick="$popover.showPopover()">Show popover</button>
<div id="$popover" popover class="backdrop"><div class="popover"></div></div>
```